# Contruir cuerpo json con mi entidad

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, wcf, restful

Tengo una consulta quiero construir el "body" de tipo string y envie el POST que contenga el json que quiero enviar para mi API REST.

Ya tengo la clase para serializar pero necesito antes contruir un objeto con todas las variables que deseo serializar de mi entidad RequerimientoModelo.

Gracias desde ya!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En linea con esta [herramienta](https://csharp2json.io/) puedes copiar y pegar tus clases y generar el json esperado en la llamada a tu controller

Comment: Coloca código en lugar de imágenes. Ley universal de StackOverflow para darle calidad a las preguntas y respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Este es un ejemplo de como puedes hacer tu llamada a la API, puede que del ejemplo tengas que modificar algunas cosas para que funcione en tu código.

Ejemplo:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ConsumirApi
{
    public class Requerimiento
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    }


    public class Resultado
    {
        public bool OcurrioError { get; set; }
        public string Mensaje { get; set; }
        public object Datos { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task<Resultado> InvocarAPI(Requerimiento req)
    {
        //Crea el cliente http con la url base de tu servidor (API)
        using (HttpClient apiClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://tuservidor") })
        {
            //url del recurso
            string recursoUrlApi = "/api/controlador/InsertaTCREQI";

            //Serializa el objeto a json
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);

            //Crea el contenido para enviar al servidor
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            //Hace el POST a la API
            HttpResponseMessage response = await apiClient.PostAsync(recursoUrlApi, content);

            //Tratamiento de la respuesta
            string resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                    return new Resultado() { OcurrioError = true, Mensaje = "ERROR" };

                try
                {
                    Resultado error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Resultado>(resp);
                    if (error == null)
                        return new Resultado() { OcurrioError = true, Mensaje = "ERROR" };

                    return error;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return new Resultado() { OcurrioError = true, Mensaje = "ERROR" };
                }
            }

            //Se asume que la API retorna un objeto de tipo "Resultado"
            Resultado respuestaOK = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Resultado>(resp);

            return respuestaOK;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar la librería de [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) para convertir tu modelo a Json.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Es confuso, pero creo que es más respuesta que comentario: "Los comentarios son notas temporales (como "Post-It") que se dejan en una pregunta o respuesta." En cambio una respuesta: "Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudará siempre..."

Comment: En este caso, se le podrian recomendar varias librerias (mejores, peores)  y ninguna seria una respuesta correcta. Por eso en este caso, parece mas un comentario que una respuesta. Ademas no hay una sola explicacion en esta respuesta que diga si quiera como se usa, o como usarlo en la pregunta de AP. La respuesta originalmente fue reportada por el sistema como de baja calidad, ya que es solamente un enlace. Tene en cuenta eso.

Comment: Pues según el enlace que pusiste "Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudará siempre..." No necesariamente debe de ser la correcta. Tienes razón con la explicación pero para el uso de la API no hay más que acudir al enlace. En fin, saludos y espero que a alguien le ayude mi comentario.